# Ask notification permission--Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, notifications

I am trying to show a pop up that ask user to grant permission notification. Because as I know.. android api less than 33 always auto on for notification permission. But not in android 33, we need to manually turn on notification permission. So, is there a way to show alert dialog to ask notification permission ? So far I have been using permission_handler but as I know, it doesn't show pop up alert for bluetooth and notification request permission

Answer (score 1):

Brother inside your manifest file you have to add a few lines you will find the build.gradle inside your project root -> android folder-> open this build.gradle file then adds these lines.

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

after this go inside your android-> app-> build.gradle and add these.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
```

}

and for permission you need to add these lines in your manifest file you will find it inside your android -> app -> src-> main -> manifest open this manifest file and these lines.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and you have to add google-services.json inside your android -> src folder.

you can get your google-services.json from firebase official site.

if you need any other help please let me know

Comment: should I install package of ```firebase_messaging``` also ?

Comment: yes you have to install a few packages I will list them below 1)  firebase_messaging: ^11.4.2
  2)firebase_core: ^1.12.0.  please give me upvote if you find this answer correct